# SQL Query - Returning specific data

Tags: sql

I'm running a query in AllScripts that provides a report of patient updates. I have all of the columns I want, and all but one is returning correctly. The other isn't incorrect, per say, but there are many values for it to return, and not the ones I want. The code:

```
SELECT PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE, PT_BASIC.NAME_LAST, 
   PT_BASIC.NAME_FIRST, 
   PT_ADMISSION.ADMIT_DATE, 
   PT_ADMISSION.TERMINATION_DATE, 
   C_DIAGNOSIS.DIAGNOSIS, 
   PT_BASIC.DATE_OF_BIRTH, PT_BASIC.SEX, 
   PT_STATUS.STATUS_CODE, 
   O_DATASET.DATASET_NAME, 
   RES_BASIC.ORGANIZATION_NAME, 
   RES_BASIC_2.NAME_FULL, 
   PT_STATUS.STATUS_DATE, 
   RES_BASIC_3.NAME_FULL NAME_FULL_2, 
   RES_BASIC_3.NAME_FIRST NAME_FIRST_2, 
   RES_BASIC_3.NAME_LAST NAME_LAST_2, 
   C_DIAGNOSIS.ICD9_CODE, 
   RES_BASIC_4.NAME_FULL NAME_FULL_3, 
   A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION, 
   res_basic_3.name_last + ', ' + res_basic_3.name_first res_basic_3_name_last_res
FROM PT_BASIC PT_BASIC
  INNER JOIN PT_ADMISSION PT_ADMISSION ON 
 (PT_ADMISSION.PATIENT_ID = PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID)
  INNER JOIN PT_STATUS PT_STATUS ON 
 (PT_STATUS.ADMISSION_ID = PT_ADMISSION.ADMISSION_ID)
  AND (PT_STATUS.PATIENT_ID = PT_ADMISSION.PATIENT_ID)
  INNER JOIN PTC_DIAGNOSIS PTC_DIAGNOSIS ON 
 (PTC_DIAGNOSIS.PT_DIAGNOSIS_ID = PT_STATUS.PRIMARY_DIAGNOSIS_ID)
  AND (PTC_DIAGNOSIS.PATIENT_ID = PT_STATUS.PATIENT_ID)
  INNER JOIN C_DIAGNOSIS C_DIAGNOSIS ON 
 (C_DIAGNOSIS.DIAGNOSIS_ID = PTC_DIAGNOSIS.DIAGNOSIS_ID)
  AND (C_DIAGNOSIS.DIAGNOSIS_SET_ID = PTC_DIAGNOSIS.DIAGNOSIS_SET_ID)
  INNER JOIN O_DATASET O_DATASET ON 
 (O_DATASET.DATASET_ID = PT_BASIC.DATASET_ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PT_ADMISSION_REFERRAL PT_ADMISSION_REFERRAL ON 
 (PT_ADMISSION_REFERRAL.REFERRAL_ID = PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID)
  FULL OUTER JOIN RES_BASIC RES_BASIC ON 
 (RES_BASIC.RESOURCE_ID = PT_ADMISSION.REFERRAL_SOURCE)
  FULL OUTER JOIN RES_BASIC RES_BASIC_2 ON 
 (RES_BASIC_2.RESOURCE_ID = PT_STATUS.ASSOCIATED_FACILITY_ID)
  FULL OUTER JOIN RES_BASIC RES_BASIC_3 ON 
 (RES_BASIC_3.RESOURCE_ID = PT_ADMISSION.PHYSICIAN_ID1)
  FULL OUTER JOIN PT_ASSIGNMENT PT_ASSIGNMENT ON 
 (PT_ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID)
  FULL OUTER JOIN A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE ON 
 (A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.ADMIN_SET_ID = PT_ASSIGNMENT.ADMIN_SET_ID)
  AND (A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.TYPE_ID = PT_ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE)
  FULL OUTER JOIN RES_BASIC RES_BASIC_4 ON 
 (RES_BASIC_4.RESOURCE_ID = PT_ASSIGNMENT.RESOURCE_ID)
WHERE 
  ( O_DATASET.DATASET_NAME = 'LIVE Seasons Hospice' )
   AND ( PT_ADMISSION.ADMIT_DATE > CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-01-01',120) )
ORDER BY PT_STATUS.STATUS_DATE DESC, 
     PT_ADMISSION.ADMIT_DATE DESC, 
     PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE
```

The part I'm working on now is A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION. In each patient, there is an assignments list. The description is the assignment type, such as social worker, or intake nurse. I am looking for PCC only. The code that pulls this information is:

```
 (PT_ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID)
  FULL OUTER JOIN A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE ON 
 (A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.ADMIN_SET_ID = PT_ASSIGNMENT.ADMIN_SET_ID)
  AND (A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.TYPE_ID = PT_ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE)
  FULL OUTER JOIN RES_BASIC RES_BASIC_4 ON 
 (RES_BASIC_4.RESOURCE_ID = PT_ASSIGNMENT.RESOURCE_ID)
```

Now, my query is getting the right number of entries, compared to a query that doesn't look for assignments, and it's pulling the right name (res_basic_4) associated with that assignment, but it's pulling assignments I don't need. I only want it to list the name of the PCC, even in cases where the resource name is blank (because no PCC has been assigned).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you mean, but is this what you're looking for?

```
FULL OUTER JOIN A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE ON 
(A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.ADMIN_SET_ID = PT_ASSIGNMENT.ADMIN_SET_ID)
AND (A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.TYPE_ID = 'PCC' OR A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.TYPE_ID IS NULL)
```

Comment: That is essentially what I'm looking for, but it returns invalid sql statement, conversion failed when converting the varcher value 'PCC' to data type smallint.

I'll give you a scenario of what I'm looking for. If I run this query, I get a report that shows me each new status update (an admission, a death, a transfer, a diagnosis change, etc.) chronologically. On each status line, I get the patient code, patient name, diagnosis, and so forth.

Comment: I want a new column for the associated PCC. Unfortunately, PCC is just a description type. Unlike where I can pull the resource for "PT_ADMISSION.PHYSICIAN_ID1" I can't use "A_ASSIGNMENT.PCC_ID1" and get the resource name for it. That doesn't exist. What does exist is A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE, which is where I get A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION. There are lots of different descriptions: Intake nurse, Registered Nurse, Volunteer, and so forth. One of these is PCC.

Comment: Well, there is probably an integer value that corresponds to 'PCC'.  In a normalized database there may be a table that tells you the conversion.  In any case, if 'PCC' is the description, you should be able to look up the type id with a query like `SELECT DISTINCT A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.TYPE_ID FROM A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE WHERE A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION = 'PCC'`

Comment: I want to see the name of the patient's PCC on their status line. The problem I'm running into is that I can either have it list _every_ type of description for a patient's status (which means each status will have upwards of 10 lines, one line for each assignment type), or it lists only the patients who have a PCC -- it doesn't display the status if the PCC field is blank.

Comment: So, for example, if the PCC type id turns out to be 4, you would write that portion of your join condition as:  `AND (A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.TYPE_ID = 4 OR A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.TYPE_ID IS NULL)`

Comment: Okay, remember that databases treat blanks differently from nulls.  A smallint field won't be blank, like a character field, but it could be null.  And nulls fail comparisons, which is why you need the IS NULL or IS NOT NULL syntax.

Comment: I have it so it's returning every status that has a PCC attached to it. That was done by changing `FULL OUTER JOIN PT_ASSIGNMENT PT_ASSIGNMENT ON (PT_ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID)` to `FULL OUTER JOIN PT_ASSIGNMENT PT_ASSIGNMENT ON (PT_ASSIGNMENT.PATIENT_ID = PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID) WHERE (A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION = 'PCC')`.

However, I still need to see the statuses where the PCC (the resource name) is empty (because there isn't a PCC). It's removing those statuses because there is no PCC attached to them (and there shouldn't be).

Comment: Be careful about moving a join condition into the where clause, or vice versa; they can have different effects. But, if this is what you want for this case, then try `WHERE (A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION = 'PCC' OR A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION IS NULL)`. (Because this is a character field, you might also have to match an empty string value, but if the join simply isn't returning a record, then the Description should be null, and this should work.)

Comment: Adding that to WHERE returns 1005 records, but there should be 1308 records. What's missing are the records that don't have PCCs attached to them. I can't get them to show up unless I get rid of the assignment type portion altogether. Sorry this has been such a headache for you too!

Comment: Looking at it again, this really has to go into the join condition, not the WHERE clause. The reason it has to go into the join condition is that otherwise you will never see the missing records. So try taking this out of the WHERE clause and add it back to the ON clause for the assignment type table join: `AND (A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION = 'PCC' OR A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION IS NULL)`

Comment: I put it into the join condition it is displaying the correct number of records, but it isn't correctly reporting who has a PCC and who doesn't, and for those with PCCs, the name it lists isn't the right one -- often the name isn't even from the right patient record.

`FULL OUTER JOIN PT_ASSIGNMENT PT_ASSIGNMENT ON (PT_ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID) FULL OUTER JOIN A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE ON (A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.ADMIN_SET_ID = PT_ASSIGNMENT.ADMIN_SET_ID) AND (A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION = 'PCC' OR A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION IS NULL)`

Comment: That is a bit surprising to me, since the `A_ASSIGNMENT_TYPE.DESCRIPTION` in your select list ought to be reporting on data that has passed the join condition, i.e., that description really ought to be 'PCC' or null. I doubt I can figure this out without looking at your data.  At this point, I would look around in case there is someone there with SQL experience who can act as a second set of eyes on this query, or someone you can bring in. Best of luck!